# Android studio Game speed different devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, game-development

I am making a game in Android Studio. Now my game is complete, but game speed is different on large displays...

I run my game with this timer:

```
if(timer == null){
  timer = new Timer();
  timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      if (start_flg) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            changePos();
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }, 0, 20);
}
```

changePos() looks like this:

```
    public void changePos() {
SPEED_BOX =(screenHeight/280);
        
          long time = System.nanoTime();
          double delta_time = (double) ((time - last_time) / 1000000)/10;
          last_time = time;
        
          // Move Box
          if (action_flg) {
            // Touching
            boxY += SPEED_BOX*delta_time;
            box.setImageDrawable(imageBox1);
          } else {
            // Releasing
            boxY -= SPEED_BOX*delta_time;
            box.setImageDrawable(imageBox2);
          }
        
          // Check box position.
          if (boxY < 0) {
            boxY = 0;
            box.setImageDrawable(imageBox1);
          }
          if (frameWidth - boxSize < boxY) {
            boxY = frameWidth - boxSize;
            box.setImageDrawable(imageBox2);
          }
          
          box.setY(boxY);
    }
```

id correct that my deltaTime is allways between 1.5 to 2.9?

but every time I try it in different ways always game speed is not correct.
Is it possible to make my game running same speed on different devices, different screen sizes?

Comment: Can you define what game speed means? Do I understand correctly that there is a box at the screen and that box is moving down? You want that the box falls from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen in certain fixed time,

Comment: In my opinion the logic seems to be correct if `screenHeight` is in pixels. Be aware of that  the [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) might not be executed after 20ms. That's just the earliest possible time, when `changePos()` could be called.

Comment: Yes there is a box and that box is moving down, but on every device is that speed different

Comment: What's `screenHeight`? Is it pixels?

Comment: yes it is pixels
`WindowManager windowManager = getWindowManager();`
   ` Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();`
    `Point size = new Point();`
    `display.getSize(size);`
    `screenWidth = size.x;`
    `screenHeight = size.y;`

Comment: How big is the difference in speed? Could it caused by rounging error? For example `SPEED_BOX =(screenHeight/280);` will return int which might not be accured enough.

Comment: Difference in speed is around a half second between large 10 inch tablet and small mobille phone 5.5 inch, SPEEDBOX is double; in log it has a value for example: `speed: 6.4071428571428575`

Comment: is really correct how i calculate deltaTime and how I use it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225895/discussion-between-matias-lappalainen-and-mask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `screenHeight` was screens height in pixels but the game does not use the whole screen. This caused that the speed was different on different devices. So screenHeight should be changed to `gamesLayout.getHeight()`.